# Use \newline between amsrefs fields

Tags: line-breaking, amsrefs

I use amsrefs package to format bibliography. The problem is that sometimes the lines are very badly typeset. The problem is often caused by a doi field. See the image below.
[image: Part of the bibliography]

I would accept manual line break, even if the entry is not ragged on the right side. Simple \newline in the pages field leaves a comma in the line, which look badly (see the image below)

[image: bad comma on the right]

Any idea how to manually break lines with proper punctuation markstreatment?
Here comes the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\renewcommand{\PrintDOI}[1]{DOI~#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{14}{article}{
  author={Kim, S.G.},
  title={The unit ball},
  journal={Kyungpook Math. J.},
  volume={53},
  date={2013},
  pages={295--306},
  doi={10.5666/KMJ.2013.53.2.295},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: although it's not ams style, my inclination is to set the entire bibliography ragged right.  url's and doi's are making a shambles of the idea of justified bibliographies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this extremely dirty hack?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\renewcommand{\PrintDOI}[1]{DOI~#1}
\begin{document}

\DefineSimpleKey{bib}{doinewline}    
\BibSpec{article}{%
    +{}  {\PrintAuthors}                {author}
    +{,} { \textit}                     {title}
    +{.} { }                            {part}
    +{:} { \textit}                     {subtitle}
    +{,} { \PrintContributions}         {contribution}
    +{.} { \PrintPartials}              {partial}
    +{,} { }                            {journal}
    +{}  { \textbf}                     {volume}
    +{}  { \PrintDatePV}                {date}
    +{,} { \issuetext}                  {number}
    +{,} { \eprintpages}                {pages}
    +{,} { }                            {status}
    +{}  {, \newline\PrintDOI}          {doinewline}
    +{,} { \PrintDOI}                   {doi}
    +{,} { available at \eprint}        {eprint}
    +{}  { \parenthesize}               {language}
    +{}  { \PrintTranslation}           {translation}
    +{;} { \PrintReprint}               {reprint}
    +{.} { }                            {note}
    +{.} {}                             {transition}
    +{}  {\SentenceSpace \PrintReviews} {review}
}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{14}{article}{
  author={Kim, S.G.},
  title={The unit ball},
  journal={Kyungpook Math. J.},
  volume={53},
  date={2013},
  pages={295--306},
  doinewline={10.5666/KMJ.2013.53.2.295},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\linebreak` command to get a line break with proper placement of the punctuation. See Section 8.5 of the [package documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) for more details:

> ### Section 8.5 Line breaks in the bibliography
>
> Suppose you need to recommend to LaTeX that it break a line in a particular
> place. Suggesting a line break in the middle of a field presents no difficulties: just edit your final `.bbl` file and insert a `\linebreak` command:
>
> ```
> subtitle={Toward a transformative hermeneutics\linebreak[3] of quantum gravity},
> ```
>
> But what if you need to force a line break *between* two fields? At first blush you might fear that
>
> ```
> subtitle={...hermeneutics of quantum gravity\linebreak[3]},
> ```
>
> will cause a line break before the comma that `amsrefs` normally inserts after the title:
> [image: Comma is placed after the line break instead of before.]
> Have no fear; `amsrefs` will detect this and automatically move the comma in front of the line break, as desired:
> [image: Comma is placed before the line break as desired.]